# How can I display existing node content in its node form?

Tags: i18n-l10n, nodes

I have several fields that need to be translated and it would be best if the translator sees the **to-be-translated** content right **beside** the **translation field**.

In a standard node form, it shows that field as an input text area field for updating purposes but I don't want the translator to touch that or be able to mess with that.

I want the translator to 'see' the rendered display of that "**to-be-translated**" field next, under or above the text area field for the translation on the node form. How to do that?

I'm not very strong in php so if you give advise with php, please be thorough. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way that I recently found was by using panels where you can actually place different components in different places. These components would then be either the rendered to-be-translated field beside the translation field. So you could say that this is a solution but I'm not very sure if this is going to require me to do this for each and every role differently or if panels could only be used to kick in only when a specific condition is met i.e. user has 'translator' role.